# TCP/IP CLIENT RECEIVE MULTIPLE MESSAGE

Tags: c#

I need a help about my server. I have a program that sends a message over a socket with a TCP/IP connection and gets acknowledgment. My current problem is: I'm sending data to the machine I'm using for it to print. The machine confirms that it has received the data each time. But now it has to give feedback that it has printed the data after confirming that it has received the data. In the program I wrote, I cannot receive 2 messages in a row from the machine. What do I need to do to listen to multiple messages over Socket?

The code I use is below. Thanks for helps...

```
private void clientBaglanti(string ipAdres, int portNumarasi)
    {
        try
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse(ipAdres); //ipHost.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, portNumarasi);
            soket = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        catch (Exception rt)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(rt.Message);
        }

                 string sonMesaj;
                    sonMesaj = gonderilenText.ToCharArray().Aggregate("", (sonuc, c) => sonuc += ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sonuc) && (sonuc.Length + 1) % 3 == 0) ? " " : "") + c.ToString());


                    byte[] gonderilenVeri = sonMesaj.Split().Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
                    byte b = checksumHesap(gonderilenVeri);
                    string txtChecksum = b.ToString("X2");

                    string toplamMesaj = sonMesaj + (" ") + txtChecksum;


                    byte[] gonderilenSonVeri = toplamMesaj.Split().Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
                    int byteGonderilen = soket.Send(gonderilenSonVeri);
                    string stringGidenVeri = BitConverter.ToString(gonderilenSonVeri);


                    lstVtMakineHaberlesme.Items.Add("Gönderilen: " + stringGidenVeri);

                    byte[] cevap = new byte[1024];
                    int ht = soket.Receive(cevap);

                    string stringGelenVeri = BitConverter.ToString(cevap, 0, ht);
                    lstVtMakineHaberlesme.Items.Add("Gelen: " + stringGelenVeri);
```

Comment: TCP doesn't do *messages*, it does an endless stream of bytes. `Receive` calls are *not* matched 1-1 with `Send` calls at the other end. So if you want to do messages, it's up to *you* to do message framing (e.g. using delimiters, sending message length first, fixed-length message(s)) atop TCP - or switch to a higher-level protocol that already does the message part for you.

Comment: TCP/IP isn't datagram/message based. It's a streaming based protocol. So there are no separate messages.

Comment: The reason I say message is because I call it my data's :). I am aware that TCP connection is not a messaging program. In my code u can see i am sending bytes already

Comment: But the point is this - say that you have 3 calls of `Send` on one side, each of which sends `50` bytes. You *could* have that you first call of `Receive` is given 25 bytes (the 1st 25 from the first `Send` call) and your next call to `Receive` gets 125 bytes.